# What should one study for Platform Developer 2 exam?

Tags: platform-developer-2

I have completed my Platform developer 1 exam, now I want to study for Platform Developer 2. I checked the study guide, but don't know where to begin. Anyone who has given Platform developer 2 can throw some light.

Comment: I always feel this type of discussion based questions should always be posted as community and answered as community.Not sure my view is right or not?

Comment: I took the transition exam, and I felt that the topics on the study guide were very representative of what was on the test.

Comment: Saw similar questions about app builder nd Devloper 1 here and hence asked

Comment: Have you looked at the Certification Study Guide from Salesforce Certification? Its at http://certification.salesforce.com/SG_CertifiedPlatformDeveloperII.pdf?v=7. Also see http://certification.salesforce.com/platform-developers. Pay attention to the distribution of questions among the different subject areas.